# What is the difference between these two queries; 891 vs 49 Results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, subquery, left-join

Environment: MS SQL Server 2008.

I have the following two queries, one returns 891 rows, which is wrong, the other 49, the correct result size. Both the queries use two sub-queries and they both are essentially the same except that the order of sub-queries is flipped.

The sub-query commented as `Entitlements` returns the rows the logged in user is entitled to see the other sub-query further restricts by user search criteria.

Can anybody please explain why the result-set size is different?

I think it has to do with the `Entitlement` sub-query using a `left outer join` and the fact that `where clause` acts to filter the results in the very end of the fetch process. But not sure.

Query 1 (Wrong result set):

```
    select
    this_.PROFILE_ID as y0_,
    personalda1_.lastName as y1_,
    personalda1_.fullName as y2_ 
from
    PROFILE this_ 
inner join
    PERSONALDATA personalda1_ 
        on this_.PERSONALDATA_ID=personalda1_.PERSONALDATA_ID 
where
    this_.PROFILE_ID in (
        /* Entitlements */ select
            this_.PROFILE_ID as y0_ 
        from
            PROFILE this_ 
        left outer join
            APPOINTMENTDETAILS appointmen1_ 
                on this_.PROFILE_ID=appointmen1_.PROFILE_ID 
        left outer join
            OTHERAPPOINTMENT othera2_ 
                on this_.PROFILE_ID=othera2_.PROFILE_ID 
        where
            (
                appointmen1_.orgUnit='00000177'
                or othera2_.organizationUnit='00000177'
            )
    ) 
    and this_.PROFILE_ID in (
        /* criteria query */ select
            distinct this_.PROFILE_ID as y0_ 
        from
            PROFILE this_ 
        inner join
            APPOINTMENTDETAILS appointmen1_ 
                on this_.PROFILE_ID=appointmen1_.PROFILE_ID 
        where
            appointmen1_.endDate='9999-12-31'
            and appointmen1_.area='ABCD'
    ) 
order by
    personalda1_.lastName asc;
```

Query 2 (Correct Result set):

```
    select
    this_.PROFILE_ID as y0_,
    personalda1_.lastName as y1_,
    personalda1_.fullName as y2_ 
from
    PROFILE this_ 
inner join
    PERSONALDATA personalda1_ 
        on this_.PERSONALDATA_ID=personalda1_.PERSONALDATA_ID 
where
    this_.PROFILE_ID in (
        select
            distinct this_.PROFILE_ID as y0_ 
        from
            PROFILE this_ 
        inner join
            APPOINTMENTDETAILS appointmen1_ 
                on this_.PROFILE_ID=appointmen1_.PROFILE_ID 
        where
            appointmen1_.endDate='9999-12-31'
            and appointmen1_.area='ABCD'
    ) 
    and this_.PROFILE_ID in (
    /* Entitlements */ select
            this_.PROFILE_ID as y0_ 
        from
            PROFILE this_ 
        left outer join
            APPOINTMENTDETAILS appointmen1_ 
                on this_.PROFILE_ID=appointmen1_.PROFILE_ID 
        left outer join
            OTHERAPPOINTMENT other2_ 
                on this_.PROFILE_ID=other2_.PROFILE_ID 
        where
            (
                appointmen1_.orgUnit='00000177'
                or other2_.organizationUnit='00000177'
            )            
    ) 
order by
    personalda1_.lastName asc;
```

Trying to understand the query execution plan but not finding it easy to follow.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you swap around the two parts of the where clause, these two queries are identical apart from a slightly different alias on one table. As the where clause is two parts and both criteria need to be met, there is no reason I can see why these are any different! Are you running both of these on the same database?

Comment: Yes, running against the same database.

Comment: `IN ( SELECT DISTINCT ...` is a bad smell - if you're lucky, the optimizer will realise it's redundant. If you're unlucky, the optimizer will decide to actually do the work to make the results distinct before assessing whether any one row fits the `IN()` criteria. Also, any reason for the change in alias name between the two (`othera2_` vs `other2_`)?

Comment: no the difference in aliases is just a type.

Comment: I mean just a typo. Will take distinct out.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the 'bad' results and find a record that should *not* be returned. Try to figure out why it's getting included, and you'll probably find the problem.

Also, you don't need the `distinct` in the subquery.

Also: is this the same as the correct query?

```
SELECT
    this_.PROFILE_ID as y0_,
    personalda1_.lastName as y1_,
    personalda1_.fullName as y2_ 
from
    PROFILE this_ 
inner join
    PERSONALDATA personalda1_ 
        on this_.PERSONALDATA_ID=personalda1_.PERSONALDATA_ID 
where
    this_.PROFILE_ID in (
        /* Entitlements */ 
        select
            this_.PROFILE_ID as y0_ 
        from
            PROFILE this_ 
        left outer join
            APPOINTMENTDETAILS appointmen1_ 
                on this_.PROFILE_ID=appointmen1_.PROFILE_ID 
        left outer join
            OTHERAPPOINTMENT othera2_ 
                on this_.PROFILE_ID=othera2_.PROFILE_ID 
        where
            (
                appointmen1_.orgUnit='00000177'
                or othera2_.organizationUnit='00000177'
            )
        AND
            appointmen1_.endDate='9999-12-31'
        AND
            appointmen1_.area='ABCD'
    )
```

Comment: This query returns 41 rows, as opposed to 49 in the 'correct' one. The redundancy of 'distinct' noted. Will follow your advice about tracking a 'bad' row. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, listing to help others in the same situation:

It was `R2`, as in `MS SQLServer2008 R2`.

Turned out one server was plain old `SQLServer 2008` without `R2` installed and the other is `R2`.

When these queries were run on `R2`, both produced same results.